# Usage of "a couple of"

Tags: adverbs, sentence-structure

Someone wrote:

> Over the last days , I’ve read **a couple of my friends’ entries** on the web about how **tremendously** picturesque places look in snowy winter, and I wish it snowed and got colder in Warsaw too.

I refined it to:

> **Over the past few days**, I’ve read **a couple of entries** from my friends about **how picturesque** places look in **a** snowy winter, and I **wished it would snow** and get colder in Warsaw too.

I just did these corrections or suggestions based on my intuitions, but don't know if I was correct or not.

- I think after "a couple of" I should use a noun like "entries" something without a possessive construction, am I right?
- I omitted "on the web" because in my version it would make the sentence too wordy and I didn't find a good place for it. where it could be placed?

Comment: "a couple of my friends' entries" is idiomatic spoken English. Your improvement is less "crowded" but there's no grammatical reason to change it. The improvement is not a "correction".

Comment: @tromano do you mean his original sentence is grammatical and natural?

Comment: @TRomano  *Over the last days....* bothers me. Would it be grammatical but not idiomatic in this context (as opposed to *Over the last days of the month/year etc*?

Comment: @Ronald Sole: I agree, but I wasn't going to proofread the entire sentence. I was responding to the specific question about the possessive.

Comment: @tromano there are other specific questions like is it " how beautiful ..." or "how very beautiful  ...". Moreover, i think specifying what's idiomatic should be allowed on this site

Comment: Ahmad, that's twice now that you have inferred what was not implied. My earlier comment did not imply that the entire sentence was idiomatic, only one part of it that you wanted to "correct". And my later comment does not suggest that questions about what is idiomatic are off-topic. I'm not addressing everything in the your question because you're supposed to ask one question per question. You've got at least two questions here (plural possessives, for one, and tense shifts).  Most of the assumptions you make in your question are incorrect.

Comment: @tromano you're right. I'm shifting them to new questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> **In** the past few days, I’ve read a couple of entries from my friends
>   about how picturesque **everything looks** **during** a **white** winter, and **so** I **wish** it would snow and get colder **here** in **Warsaw,** too.